# android twitter4j replies posts in my profile

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I've created an application that uses twitter4j, but retweets & replies posts in my profile, but not in user's profile.

```
private void authorize(){
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setUser(userLogin);
        cb.setPassword(userPassword);
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(mConsKey);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(mConsSecret);
        cb.setOAuthAccessToken(mAccessToken);
        cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(mAccessTokenSecret);

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

        twitter = tf.getInstance();

        if(twitter != null){
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS);
        }else{
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED);
        }
    }

private void reply(){
    try{
        twitter.updateStatus(new StatusUpdate(replyText)
                .inReplyToStatusId(status.getId()));
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(END_USER_ACTION);
    }catch(TwitterException tEx){
        Log.e(tEx.getExceptionCode(), tEx.toString());
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED);
    }

}

private void retwit(){
    try{
        twitter.retweetStatus(status.getId());
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(END_USER_ACTION);
    }catch(TwitterException tEx){
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED);
    }
}
```

what i'm doing wrong?